# Ocultar un div dependiendo de la categoría de WooComerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

¡Buenos días a todos!

Estoy intentado ocultar un div durante el loop de carga de productos de WooCoomerce. Este muestra un texto de "Envió gratis 24 Horas" que debe desaparecer al cargar los productos de una categoría especifica.

El código que tengo implementado no me funciona debido a que muestra ese div en todos los productos, aunque haga un filtro.

```
<?php $categ = $product->get_categories();
                if ($categ != 'maquinaria') {
                        echo '<div class="enviogratis"> <span class="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></span> Envío Gratis 24 horas</div>';
            } ?>
```

Podrían echarle un vistazo. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo he solucianado así.

```
<?php global $post;
                        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
                        foreach ($terms as $term) {
                        $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;

                            if ($product_cat_id != 'ID de tu categoría') {
                                echo 'Tu mensaje';
                            }
                        break;
            }

                 ?>
```

Saludos

Comment: Hola Joshua, Me alegro que lo solucionaras, sin embargo con la informacion de tu pregunta jamas podriamos haber conseguido la respueta. De donde sale ese `98`?  Como eso, falta informacion que no diste en la pregunta. No creo que esta respuesta sea de utilidad a otros users porque parece propia de tu proyecto. Un saludo

Comment: Ese Valor es el valor de la categoría. Es decir el ID de la misma ;-)

Comment: Acabo de editarlo para que quede mejor explicado 
;-)